# Intersection of a unit sphere of a given norm in finite dimension with an hyperplane.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $C:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\,\|x\| \leq 1\}$, that is to say let $C$ be a convex compact symmetric set of non empty interior. Let $H$ be a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n-1$. Is it true that there exists $z\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such as $\|z\|=1$ and
\begin{align*}
\Big[(H \cap \partial C) + \mathbb{R}z\Big] \cap \mathring{C} = \emptyset \quad\text{ ? }
\end{align*}
If not, please, give me a counter-example ! It appears to me that $z\in H^\perp$ should be a proper candidate, but though I might see why this is working for the $\| \cdot \|_p$ norms for example in low dimensions, I did not manage to prove it generally.

Thanks in advance.

Xou.

Comment: Did you mean $\leq$ in the definition of $C$?

Comment: What's for you $\,\Bbb Rz\,$??

Comment: @DonAntonio: Presumably $\{\lambda z \}_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}}$?

Comment: what is $\mathring{C}$?

Comment: Most likely the interior.

Comment: Presumably you mean $z \neq 0$, since the result is trivially true in that case?

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant $\leq$ and $z\neq 0$ (I corrected both). As for the two other questions, the given answers are correct !

Answer (score 2):

If $z \neq 0$ the result is not true in general.

Here is a counterexample.

Let $C = \{ (x_1,x_2) | x_1^2+x_2^2 = 1 \}$. Let $H$ = $\{ x | x_2 = \sqrt{2}\}$. Then $H \cap \partial C = \{(\pm \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})^T \}$, and $(H \cap \partial C) + \mathbb{R}z = \{ \lambda z + \sqrt{2} (1,1)^T,  \lambda z + \sqrt{2} (-1,1)^T \}_{\lambda  \in \mathbb{R}} $.

[image]

(Picture inspired by @robjohn.)

Now let $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{2} (x_1^2+x_2^2)$ and let $z \neq 0$. We will show that for any $z$, there exists $ x \in H \cap \partial C$ and a $\lambda$ such that $\phi(x+\lambda z) < \frac{1}{2}$, which implies that $x+\lambda z \in C^\circ$.

In particular, all we need to do is to show that $\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x} z \neq 0$, since if this is the case, it is straightforward to show that there exists a $\lambda$ such that $\phi(x+\lambda z) < \phi(x) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Suppose, to the contrary, that $\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x}z = x^T z = 0$ for all $ x \in H \cap \partial C$. Then this implies that $ \sqrt{2} (\pm 1, 1) z = 0$, which implies that $z = 0$ since $(\pm 1, 1)^T$ are linearly independent, which contradicts our assumption that $z \neq 0$.

Comment: By $\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x}$, do you mean $\nabla\phi$? At least it seems that $\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x}$ is supposed to be a vector. Assuming so, then this looks good (+1).

Comment: @robjohn: Sort of, $\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x} h = \langle \nabla\phi(x), h \rangle $. $\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x}\in (\mathbb{R}^n)^*$, whereas $\nabla\phi \in \mathbb{R}^n$. (And thanks!)

Comment: I am so sorry, I think my english is not good enough : I meant a *linear* hyperplan (i.e. containing 0), that is a subspace of dimension $n-1$. In your example, you could only use lines crossing zero, and you may check that the orthogonal direction does the job for $z$.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am misunderstanding something, the following seems to be a counterexample.

Given the standard Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the plane $x_1=.6$, $H\cap\partial C$ is the circle
$$
\{x:x_1=.6\text{ and }x_2^2+x_3^2=.64\}
$$
No matter what $z$ is (other than $0$), the elliptic cylinder $(H \cap \partial C) + \mathbb{R}z$ will intersect $\mathring{C}$.

$\hspace{3.3cm}$[image]

Given any $z$, if there is an $h\in H\cap\partial C$ so that $h+\mathbb{R}z$ does not intersect $\mathring{C}$, then $z$ must be perpendicular to the normal to $\partial C$ at $h$. In order that $h+\mathbb{R}z$ does not intersect $\mathring{C}$ for all $h\in H\cap\partial C$, $z$ would have to be perpendicular to each normal to $\partial C$ at a point of $H\cap\partial C$.

Therefore, $z$ would need to be perpendicular to $(.6,.8,0)$ and $(.6,0,.8)$, thus parallel to their cross product $(.64,-.48,-.48)$. Furthermore, $z$ would need to be perpendicular to $(.6,-.8,0)$ and $(.6,0,.8)$, thus parallel to their cross product $(-.64,-.48,.48)$. However, since $(.64,-.48,-.48)$ and $(-.64,-.48,.48)$ are not parallel, $z$ cannot be parallel to them both, unless it is $0$.

Thus, there is no $z$ that so that $\left[(H\cap\partial C)+\mathbb{R}z\right]\cap\mathring{C}=\emptyset$.

**Revised Question**

Consider the [maximum norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Maximum_norm_.28special_case_of:_infinity_norm.2C_uniform_norm.2C_or_supremum_norm.29) on $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$$
\|x\|=\max(|x_1|,|x_2|,|x_3|)
$$
Under this norm, $C$ is a cube of side $2$.

Let $H$ be the plane $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$. This plane intersects all $6$ sides of $\partial C$. Each of the following points is on $H$ and a different side of $\partial C$:
$$
\small\left\{\left(1,-\frac12,-\frac12\right),\left(-\frac12,1,-\frac12\right),\left(-\frac12,-\frac12,1\right),\left(-1,\frac12,\frac12\right),\left(\frac12,-1,\frac12\right),\left(\frac12,\frac12,-1\right)\right\}
$$

As argued in the answer to the original question, $z$ must be perpendicular to the normal to $C$ at all points of $H\cap\partial C$. However, the normals to the cube span $\mathbb{R}^3$, so there can be no such $z$ other than $z=0$.

**True in Two**

Due to the fact that $\|-x\|=\|x\|$, the normal to $\partial C=\{x:\|x\|=1\}$ at any $x$ is the opposite of the normal at $-x$. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, $H\cap\partial C$ consists of two points, $h$ and $-h$. Thus, if $z$ is perpendicular to the normal to $\partial C$ at $h$, then neither $h+\mathbb{R}z$ nor $-h+\mathbb{R}z$ intersect $\mathring{C}$.

Comment: Same remark as above. I am so sorry because you both gave good, precise and furthermore drawn answers ! Since the plane has to pass through zero, again the orthogonal direction seems to work (the intersection is made through one of the "big circles" of the sphere).

Comment: @xounamoun: Unfortunately, the subspace $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$ fails against the [maximum norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Maximum_norm_.28special_case_of%3a_infinity_norm.2C_uniform_norm.2C_or_supremum_norm.29).

Comment: Ok, I agree ! Thanks !

Comment: @xounamoun: However, it appears to be true in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this before, this is probably because the intersection seems to be always reduced to 2 points. Actually, this question is related to a lemma used in the study of Schauder bases. I was quite sure that the result may not be true generally in finite dimension because it would simplify considerably some classical proof ! Ok I just read the proof " true in two ", I agree also !